# bootstrap dropdown-menu background-color not working in IE

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu, cross-browser

I've got a background-color on a drop-down menu that only applies the background color on the active menu li instead of all of the menu options. It works in all other browsers except for IE--

```
.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: @zindex-dropdown;
  display: none; // none by default, but block on "open" of the menu
  float: left;
  min-width: 154px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin-left: 0px; // override default ul
  list-style: none;
  font-size: @font-size-base;
  background-color: @dropdown-bg;
  border-radius: @border-radius-base;
  .box-shadow(0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175));
  background-clip: padding-box;
```

Any insight is appreciated - thank you!!
http://soakandswim.com/pools/inground/ - reference

Comment: What's the `background-color` in the CSS?

Comment: @mooseman It's #3d8fca;

Comment: @Mooseman I'm actually thinking that it's more of a cross-browsing error with the display class rather than the background color not rendering

Comment: @Mooseman `.nav .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu { display: block; }
.nav .dropdown.active .dropdown-menu { display: flex; display: -webkit-box;}`